# Database designs for customizable user feeds per group (so not social)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating an application where there are multiple groups that contain a feed of messages. I need to know which message is read for X person. The feed should also be customizable per user.

I was thinking about using the following database structure:

```
messages
  - id (PK)
  - user_id (user that created the message)
  - text
  - group_id
  - created_at

objects
  - id (PK)
  - user_id (user that should receive the object in his timeline)
  - parent_type (can be `message` or some other resource)
  - parent_id (the `id` of the resource based on the type)
  - seen (boolean that indicates if the user has seen the object)
```

When a message is created for a group, I'll create a record in the `messages` table and create records for **every** member of the group in the `objects` table.

The only thing that is currently holding me back is, that there might be groups that consist of ~1000-2000 users at max. For every message created in those groups, there will be created 1000-2000 records in the `objects` table.

Will this be a problem and how could I solve this if it might be?

Comment: How does WhatsApp do it?

Comment: If you need to know if a person has read a message, that is just a 2-column table with person_id and message_id.

Comment: @RickJames I also need to know who haven't read the message

Comment: That sounds like a `LEFT JOIN` involving the group-membership table.